# Can't download from Play Store - need new ideas to try

Tags: google-play-store, downloading

I've had this Moto X (1st ed) for a few years. For the last 3 weeks or so I've been unable to use the Play Store to update any of my apps or to download any new ones. The store otherwise works just fine: I get notification of updates, I can browse the store...

Problem is, once I hit `Update` or `Accept` to update or install, the status shown is stuck at `Downloading...` indefinitely with no progress; even if I let it sit for hours, there is never any error message.  Here's what I've already tried:

1. Made sure there is enough space to install/update apps
2. Cleared the cache for Play Store and Play Services apps, and restarted the phone.
3. Uninstalled Play Store updates `Settings >> Apps >> Google Play Store >> Uninstall Updates` and restarted the phone. Even the old version of the store wouldn't download anything.
4. Used [a mirror site](https://www.apkmirror.com/?post_type=app_release&searchtype=apk&s=google+play+services) to download and update Google App, Google Play Store, and Google Play Services to the most recent version (more recent than what I had before `#3`). I think these APKs were genuine since the signatures must have matched what was already installed or the update would have been blocked
5. Switched from WiFi to Cell data.

I've gone through the similar questions from the [troubleshooting FAQ](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) but didn't come across something else to try.  Any help would be welcome.

- Moto X on Android 5.1
- Google Play Services 10.5.53
- Google Play Store 7.7.09.N-all

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the download manager (`com.android.providers.downloads`). Please check if this package is frozen/disabled. You need  to enable it then restart your device. You can be able to download again.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat This app was not frozen/disabled but you were on the right track!  After I cleared CACHE and DATA for the native Download Manager, then rebooted the phone, downloads began working again.  Please write up a solution to this effect if you want me to select it.

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is usually caused by some kind of corruption in the download manager (`com.android.providers.downloads`).

Sometimes the issue also occurs when download manager was previously frozen. ( I have experienced this issue due to this)

**However as OP suggested the issue was fixed by clearing  the cache and data of the download manager and rebooting the device**

Comment: Don't know whether this mattered but I rebooted after clearing cache/data. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks I edited it, sometimes its important to ensure full functionality of the playstore.

Answer (score 1):

- ***Reboot your device*** and open it again
- If above steps fails,  please do clear data and cache in applications settings , and open it again for ***Google play store and play services***
- Or go for ***Third party store for android *** like ***Mobogenie***

**EDIT :**

This step will stop the Play Store and clear data stored in a temporary area of device memory. This gives the app a fresh start and can help payments process properly. It won't delete any permanent files.

**First, Force the Play Store to stop:**

- Open your device's Settings Settings. Scroll down and tap Apps or
  Application manager (depending on your device, this may be
  different).
- Tap the Google Play Store Play Store. Tap Force stop.

**Second, clear the cache and data for the Play Store:**

- Open your
  device's Settings Settings.
- Tap Apps or Application manager.
- Tap Google Play Store Play Store. Tap Storage. Tap Clear cache. Tap Clear
  data.

**Next, reopen the Play Store:**

- Open the Google Play Store app Play Store.Try your download again.

I have found these steps from this link , i hope it will help you [Click here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1267137?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en-GB)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had already rebooted the phone, and cleared CACHE for Play Store and Play Services. I didn't want to clear DATA because I don't want to lose credits for the apps I've purchased and I don't know whether clearing data would have that effect.

Comment: Please see my edited answer @BeetleJuice hope it helps you : )

Comment: +1 for trying to help me. My problem wasn't with the Play Store as I thought. It was with Download Manager app. Once I cleared its cache and restarted, the issue was resolved.